# Почему все покупки отменены?

Tags: android, android-billing

Обновил в приложении Google Play App Billing 6. Теперь для новых покупок пишет "платеж возвращен". Причем сначала платеж проходит, а "платеж возвращен" появляется через 2-3 дня.С последним, скорее всего, произойдет то же самое.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Google это не дружественная америкоцкая организация. Пользуйся отечественной валютой и отечественными способами.

Comment: @zerxa Например, какими?

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, это происходит во время процедуры проверки платежного метода. Google специально списывает и возвращает на карту покупателей нули, чтобы проверить **существование** карты. Возможно еще то, что когда люди покупали ваш цифровой товар, то им попросту не хватило денег на счету.